# Why coder tries to decode tag list during Cobine phase?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to combine some records in unbound stream. I do have a `PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>>` which I'm trying to combine using my own accumulator class `EventAccumulator` that contains two fields of type `Long` and `TableRow` picked from each window in aforementioned stream.

I've created my own clas `EventAccumulatorCoder` and I'm registering this one in the pipeline to handle instances of `EventAccumulator`. Coder looks as follows:

```
public class EventAccumulatorCoder extends AtomicCoder<EventAccumulator> {
    public static EventAccumulatorCoder of() {
        return new EventAccumulatorCoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(EventAccumulator value, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        TableRowJsonCoder.of().encode(value.getEarliestEvent(), outputStream, context);
        BigEndianLongCoder.of().encode(value.getEarliestTimestamp(), outputStream, context);
    }

    @Override
    public EventAccumulator decode(InputStream inputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        TableRow row = TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(inputStream, context);
        Long timestamp = BigEndianLongCoder.of().decode(inputStream, context);
        return new EventAccumulator(timestamp, row);
    }
}
```

During pipeline execution I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to decode tag list using EventAccumulatorCoder
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.WindmillStateReader.tagListPageValues(WindmillStateReader.java:576)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.WindmillStateReader.consumeTagList(WindmillStateReader.java:599)
...
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.BigEndianLongCoder.decode(BigEndianLongCoder.java:62)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
```

Do you guys have any idea why the coder tries to decode tag list? I need to add that the input to the combine phase is a side output from the previous pipeline step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `context.nested()` - your coder is very much like a `KvCoder`, see how `KvCoder` uses it [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/KvCoder.java#L81-L97).

You're getting the `EOFException` because `TableRowJsonCoder.of().encode(value.getEarliestEvent(), outputStream, context)`, when using the non-nested context, consumes the whole stream, that's why the next line, `BigEndianLongCoder.decode`, hits EOF.

Comment: It helped, although it's a pity that I didn't find a word about the nested context on official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/data-encoding. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.